# Flags Windows 7 window always on top INCLUDING the Win7 taskbar (Custom error)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, taskbar

I know a few flags that make the window always on top (eg Qt :: ToolTip, Qt :: WindowStaysOnTopHint, Qt :: Popup), but each time the method is the same problem.

By clicking on the start menu, the area tray, empty field between programs and tray - window and so is hiding.

Everything is fine when I switch between different applications and I click anywhere except the above-mentioned places.

Just run other applications that I used to use, so it might be a function of the uninvited Windows.

Code does not make sense given, because at the same time where do dumb mistake, and indeed act as a flag to be apart of this "small" problem.

Comment: It's just a "shortcut" to show desktop (=minimize/hide all Windows). You can do the same with WINDOWS+D keyboard shortcut. You can't programmatically prevent this (even if you instruct your application to ignore WM_SIZE messages) because Windows will hide it (and it'll be visible again when/if you restore any other window).

Comment: @Adriano, I bet it would be possible to programmatically prevent it by hooking into the process responsible, if nothing else. That said, that's extremely pedantic, but could be fun :p

Comment: @Chris I hope I won't have to do it! ;)

Comment: At a forum got the answer that WinApi this effect can be achieved by:
`SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE + SWP_NOSIZE);`

Now the question is how to move to QT?

Answer (score 0):

These things work:
    HWND hWnd = reinterpret_cast(this->winId());
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

But it turns out that exactly the same as the flag of the subject. : (

Explanation of what exactly is the problem:
http://youtu.be/k5TCtr1hPKY

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, regular exercise such thing:

```
if(this->isActiveWindow() == false} {
    this->raise();
}
```

Only the minimized window does not always work, but to me it is unnecessary.